# How to dynamicallly populate selectize using c# webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am using https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/
and I've followed their example for dynamic population

in my aspx page I have

```
        $('#stationid').selectize({
        valueField: 'value',
        labelField: 'text',
        searchField: ['text'],
        create: function (input, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Search.aspx/GetListboxValues',
                data: "{'query':'" + input+ "'}",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    return callback(response);
                }
            });
        },
        render: {
            option: function (item, escape) {
                return '<div>' + escape(item.text) + '</div>';
            }
        },
        load: function (query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Search.aspx/GetListboxValues",
                data: "{'query':'" + query + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    callback(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });



<asp:ListBox ID="stationid" Width="300" SelectionMode="Multiple"  runat="server">
    </asp:ListBox>
```

In my aspx.cs I have

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetListboxValues(string query)
    {
        string _conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string sql = "select station_name as [value], station_name as [text]  from station where station_name like '%" + query + "%' group by station_name order by station_name asc";

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);

        }


        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

    }
```

The webmethod works and returns a json in the following format

{"d":"[{\"value\":\"I-M-987\",\"text\":\"I-M-987\"},{\"value\":\"S-2987\",\"text\":\"S-2987\"},{\"value\":\"S-987\",\"text\":\"S-987\"}]"}

If I type in the listbox then selectize adds what I'm typing and fires off the webmethod but the listbox is not populating with the returned json values.  How can I solve this ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone else has this issue, the freaking problem was the json was formatted wrong. 
I needed to use eval function to get only text from json, because raw json had all those \"

so just do this

```
success: function (res) {
var rspns = eval(res.d); 
callback(rspns);
}
```